# Query data from different object

Tags: soql, query

I have 2 custom objects. Let's name it to object 1 and object 2. Both of these objects have their own field.

Object 1 have fields: Customer name, item, quantity, total, .....

object 2 have fields: Customer name, credit limit balance, .....

Both objects have customer name field, where both of them are lookup fields (to account object-standard object).

So now I want to display item, quantity, total, from object 1 to object 2 based on customer name, but I don't know how to query it. Anyone can help me?

```
Select Customername__c, item__c, quantity__c, total__c,
                             (Select Customername__c, creditlimitbalance__c From Object2__r) 
                             from Object1__c
```

I got this error:

```
Didn't understand relationship 'From Object2__r' in FROM part of query call.
```

I think because object 1 and object 2 don't have any relation. But they have field lookup to the same object (account with customer name)

I really appreciate it if you guys can help me. Do let me know if need more information. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include a subquery in a SOQL, you need to use `relationshipName`.
So lets say you have a `BoatReview__c.object` object and it has a lookup to `Boat__c.object`.

And your relationship name in `BoatReview__c.object` is `<relationshipName>Boat_Reviews</relationshipName>`

Then your query will become:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Boat_Reviews__r) FROM Boat__c
```

If you are not using proper relationship or have misspelled the name , then you will get this error. `Didn't understand relationship 'From Object2__r' in FROM part of query call.`

**If you are querying on totally unrelated objects then you need to use two separate queries.**

And I believe you want to fetch data for Object1 and Object2 where both have same account.

In that case you can query

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Object1s__r), (SELECT Id FROM Object2s__r) FROM Account
```

This will fetch all accounts and fetch  Object1s__r data and Object2s__r data in list if its there in database.

Comment: `select id, (select id from Sales__r) from account`

I do like this, but still, get the same error,

INVALID_TYPE: 
select id, (select id from Sales__r) from account
                           ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:28
Didn't understand relationship 'Sales__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Sokay I got it. Thank you for your help :-)